# Restricted generics with CDI

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection, cdi

The JSR-299 specification states in §3.1:

> If the managed bean class is a generic type, it must have scope
>   @Dependent. If a managed bean with a parameterized bean class declares
>   any scope other than @Dependent, the container automatically detects
>   the problem and treats it as a definition error.

Effectively meaning that you can't do this:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped or @RequestScoped or similar
public class MyProducer<T> {...}
```

What are the technical reasons for this decision?

Will it be remedied in an upcoming version of CDI by any chance?

Is there a best practice for dealing with /working around this?

Thank you

**EDIT** - a workaround I can often use is to inject a generic POJO-bean into a bean with the needed scope. Often, but not always.

Comment: Great question, by the way. I didn't know about this restriction, and it really gets you thinking.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here's a generic, non-dependent bean class:

```
@ApplicationScoped
public class FavouriteChooser<T> {
    public T getFavourite() {
        // ...
    }
}
```

How many instances of this bean will there be in the application?

Here is an injection site:

```
@Inject
private FavouriteChooser<String> favouriteWord;
```

And here's another:

```
@Inject
private FavouriteChooser<Integer> favouriteNumber;
```

Would you like to change your answer? :D

Ooh, and here's another:

```
@Inject
private FavouriteChooser<CharSequence> favouriteLetters;
```

EDIT. If you want a solution, i would suggest making your generic class abstract, and adding concrete subclasses which bind the type. So:

```
public abstract class MyProducer<T> {...}

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MyStringProducer extends MyProducer<String> {}

@Named
@SessionScoped
public class MyIntegerProducer extends MyProducer<Integer> {}
```

It's boilerplate, but it's only three lines per type. Bear in mind that would give you one instance per session per type, which you might not want.

Comment: Nice - so as long as you dont make the bean named, it can be injected? If the scoping is preserved (is it? - is each injected FavouriteChooser application-scoped?) than the only restriction would be that I can't access them with EL explressions? And doesnt is contradict the spec? It's supposed to be a managed bean after all.

Comment: No, my point is that this code cannot possibly work! I've declared `FavouriteChooser` application-scoped, which means there can only be one instance. But there are two injection sites for it which *cannot be satisfied by the same object*. And that, i think, is why you can't inject instances of generic classes in any scope other than dependent.

Comment: Sorry for not being clearer about what i was trying to say when i wrote this answer. I just rushed it off without having time to explain properly :/.

Comment: Now, the one thing that springs to mind is the idea of a new kind of scope, which is a type variable binding scope; if you had a scope which was "where T is String", then within that scope, you could have an instance of `FavouriteChooser` which could be injected anywhere that needed a `FavouriteChooser<String>`. But this is strictly a theoretical idea!

Comment: Also, there is a simple but ugly workaround/solution, which i have added.

Comment: Aah, now I get it (I hope)! Thanks for the example. It's the erasure again...The workaround you are proposing occured to me as well, but it tends to end with a bunch of empty classes, whose only purpose is to "degenerify" the parent class, so I have taken a different approach - injecting generic pojo-beans into properly scoped classes - seems a bit less ugly.

Comment: RE: your solution, what if you want to use `@Inject` in the parent?  Is that still forbidden because the parent is a parameterized type?  My IDE is telling me so, but I hope it's lying :)  If not, what's the work around to that?

Comment: What do you mean by "use @Inject in the parent"? You mean to inject fields declared in the abstract base class? I suspect that this is illegal, because the base class is not itself a managed class. I suggest you declare a non-injected protected constructor which takes the necessary dependencies, then inject them into and pass them on from injected constructors in the subclasses. It's a bit verbose, but it's straightforward.

Answer (score 2):

All non-dependent scoped beans have to be proxied - AFAIK this is not possible with generic types.

UPDATE:

I'd love to be able to explain that in more detail, but I'm not ;-) Weld uses [javassist](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/), and they state that [proxying generic types is possible in principle](http://www.csg.ci.i.u-tokyo.ac.jp/~chiba/javassist/tutorial/tutorial3.html#generics) - though not directly supported by the toplevel API. But we are talking about the specification, not the implementation of Weld...

Maybe someone else can fill the gap?

Comment: Thanks, jan. It sheds some light on the matter already - it would be great if you could also explain why generic types cannot be proxied (I guess it has sth to do with the principal java nemesis - type erasure but cant put my finger on it).