# CDI : inject two generics from the same template

Tags: java, generics, dependency-injection, cdi, conflict

My problem is that I cannot inject multiple templates instances from GenericManagerJPA<>.
That's to say that in this code, both projectManager and userManager will contains the same  `GenericManagerJPA<User>` instance. I don't know why...

```
@Stateless
public class UserFacadeJPA implements Serializable {

@Inject private GenericManagerJPA<Project> projectManager;
@Inject private GenericManagerJPA<User> userManager;


@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    projectManager.setEntityClass(Project.class);
    userManager.setEntityClass(User.class);
}
....
```

From this class :

```
@Dependent
@Stateless
public class GenericManagerJPA<T> implements Serializable {
...
```

How can I inject differents instances of a generic object with CDI ? 
Can you help me about this issue? Thank's a lot.

PS: I have read this thread ( https://community.jboss.org/blogs/scott.stark/2012/08/21/a-generic-producer-method ) that presents how to create it (I think) but I assume it's a bit to complicated to understand for me. So if you have another solution or if you can explain me the principle more clearly...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're running into is an EJB issue, not really a CDI issue.  The problem will go away if you remove `@Stateless` from the class `GenericManagerJPA`.  EJB doesn't deal with generics too well, unfortunately.

Comment: To clarify a bit further.  One problem is that you only end up with a single EJB reference created.  CDI is simply looking up that reference and injecting it into the field.  With pure CDI beans, you'll end up with two different injection points (since it doesn't delegate down to the EJB container to find the instance).

Comment: OK, I understand a little what you mean but how can I keep my Stateless annotation because here, my class becomes stateful isn't it ? And it doesn't work without the `@New` annotation between `@Inject` and private... It creates a problem of performance... Is there a pretty way to make that. In all cases, thank's a lot!

Comment: The problem with EJBs (not stateless, stateful, singleton specific) is that they don't deal with generics all that well from a spec standpoint.  They use interfaces to bind.  In CDI, to use generics you need to be dependent scoped.

Comment: Yes but how (with ejb or with cdi) can I use generics and being stateless. Do you have any idea about that? thx.

Comment: So, I finally decide to use the solution that you can find [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11138625/generics-and-cdi-clash)